# Template file not found after upgrade magento and theme

Tags: magento-1.9, template, theme, upgrade, not-found

I've successfull update a magento from 1.7.2 to 1.9.2 and all work fine.
Then I've upgrade the theme and now not working fine, in homepage the error is:

> CRIT (2): Not valid template file:
>   frontend/base/default/template/page/1column-wide.phtml

and other.

Really this file exist in installation, but there is in another directory, `/app/design/frontend/buyshop/default/template/page/`

I think that in DB or in some file there is a referement at this path, and with update magento this not working yet.

Answer (score 1):

**First**: refresh all cache in admin panel.
**Second**: check **Admin Panel -> Pages -> Homepage**.
In Content check custom widgets (sometimes that is case) where are custom path (maybe there is wrong?). Go to Design tab, next check **Page layout** (there you swith to another layout style ex: 1 column, 2 column etc). Change to something else and check if error exist.
**Third**: show page.xml file along with **local.xml** if exist.

Magento use fallback mechanism if cannot find template file in your custom theme. It's looking in base because there is wrong path in your custom theme xml files or page setting (after update it can occur because this place isn't update).

Pleas add this file content to response so we can help you faster if problem still exist.
Ps. First answer there, be polite :)

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your support,
1) the cache has always been disabled to avoid mistakes and still have clean
2) If I change Page layout, from 1column widh to 1 colum the page open but with default magento theme, not with buyshop theme.
3) I've not undestand what do you mean with: "show page.xml file along with local.xml if exist." where I must search/found this file?

Thanks,
Bye

Comment: The files what i mention are in:
/app/design/frontend/buyshop/default/layout/page.xml
/app/design/frontend/buyshop/default/layout/local.xml

Comment: Only this two xml in template folder can have something wrong, that template don't showing.
Pleas check what is in your 'Custom layout' (it's under the Page layout switch) - one more location of overriding default xml. 

Last check this: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-cms-page-layout/
Because, options isn't from core, then it's custom  and created by module. Check if exist and add some more information what you found.